# kotlin: How to get if EditText has setError enabled?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I validate if EditText has setError enabled ?

I want to disable a button if EditText has an error.

Any other way to achieve this.

It kinda works when I put `view.calcbutton.setEnabled(false)` inside the validateEditText-function, but I use the validateEditText-function to validate multiple EditTexts and only the last function-call disables the button.
if the first function-call disables the button, the second enables it again, and vice versa.

But I want do it outside this function because if one of the multiple EditTexts has setError the button should be disabled.

```
//global var blockcalcbutton
var blockcalcbutton = 0

//function to validate EditTexts and set blockcalcbutton=1 if setError
validateEditText(view.input_volt, view, getString(R.string.invalid_volt))

        if(blockcalcbutton == 1) {
            view.calcbutton.setEnabled(false)
            view.calcbutton.setText(getString(R.string.calcbutton_disabled))
            view.calcbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.buttonDisabled)
        } else {
            view.calcbutton.setEnabled(true)
            view.calcbutton.setText(getString(R.string.calcbutton_enabled))
            view.calcbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.buttonBackground)
        }
```

```
fun validateEditText(editText: EditText, message: String) {
        val myEditText = editText
        myEditText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

                if(myEditText.text.toString() == "" || myEditText.text.toString() == "." || myEditText.text.toString() == "0") {
                    //setError
                    myEditText.setError(message)
                    //var to disable Button 
                    blockcalcbutton = 1
                } else {
                    //delete setError
                    myEditText.setError(null)
                    //var to enable Button
                    blockcalcbutton = 0
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a callback to notify when you set an error or delete it.

```
interface EditTextErrorListener {
    fun onErrorSet()
    fun onErrorDeleted()
}
```

Here you can notify:

```
if(myEditText.text.toString() == "" || myEditText.text.toString() == "." || myEditText.text.toString() == "0") {
    //setError
    myEditText.setError(message)
  --->  listener.onErrorSet()
    //var to disable Button 
    blockcalcbutton = 1
} else {
    //delete setError
    myEditText.setError(null)
  --->  listener.onErrorDeleted()
    //var to enable Button
    blockcalcbutton = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try approaching the problem from further away; when you look at this issue, you have multiple inputs (all the fields in your form) and one boolean output:

1. All fields are OK -> Enable the button
2. One or more fields are NOT Ok -> disable the button.

Additionally, you have local validation on each field (to display the error, etc.).

I'd argue that the local validation on each field, is to be done at the callback from the edit text (onAfterText, etc.etc.). You are already doing this.

A way to ensure the final validation (of the form as a whole) is fast, you could use a reference counter. E.g.:

Each edit text, validates with `afterTextChanged`. Each one performs whatever validation you think is right (can be a shared one if they are all the same).

If validation fails, you keep a reference to the failed field.

This will not have side-effects because nothing happens whether the item [is](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-set/remove.html) or [is not](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-set/add.html) on the list.

This is some pseudo-code:

```
// keep a list of fields (this is just a way to do it, there are many others)
var errorFields = MutableHashSet<EditText>
```

later in your "validation" (afterTextChanges for example):

```
if (xxx && yyy && zzz) { //your validations for the individual editText
  //setError
  myEditText.setError(message)

  // Store the reference of the editField in error.
  errorFields.add(theEditTextThatHasAFailure).
} else {
  myEditText.setError(null)
  // If the validation is ok, you remove it:
  errorFields.remove(theEditTextThatHasFailure)
}

// The form may have changed, update the global button state.
updateButtonState();
```

All this method needs to do, is something like:

```
button.enabled = errorFields.isEmpty()
```

This will only be empty if there are no error fields.

This is just an idea you may need to combine with callbacks for further control, but remember this one thing:

EditTexts (or any other widget) is and should not be responsible for the business logic that drives the whole "Form"; they are merely individual pieces of a larger puzzle, and as such, it's incorrect to give them the responsibility to drive your Form's validations; they can (and should) however, validate themselves and handle their own error state (like you're doing), but that's as far as it should go.

They can inform of a state change (e.g. via the listener onAfterText, or after gaining/losing focus, etc.) but shouldn't make business logic decisions. EditTexts are designed to take user input and display it on screen, that's all.

Last but not least, don't forget to remove the references when you destroy your views

```
onDestroy() {
   errorFields.clear()
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Your hint with a separate updateButtonState()-function did the trick for me, but I kept my blockcalcbutton-variable.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what the variable is for, but I didn't include all your code, just a simplified version. :) Keep in mind that you cannot track the validity of more than one field with a single boolean flag (this is the problem you were having).